# How to have a single UserControl added to baseform but with different event handlers for same event in the inheriting pages?

Tags: asp.net, delegates, overriding

This is my application setup :

I have a UserControls folder in my application inside which there is my .ascx file which happnes to contain just a simple ASP Button. I have not added any code in the code-behind of the ascx.

I have a BaseForm.cs (just a C# class file and NOT an aspx file) which is inheriting from System.Web.UI.Page

```
public class BaseForm : System.Web.UI.Page {
    protected override void OnInit(EventArgs e)
    {
        UserControls.UserButton1 ObjUserControls=(UserControls.UserButton1)LoadControl("~/UserControls/UserButton1.ascx");
        ObjUserControls.ID = "UserControl1";
        this.Form.Controls.Add(ObjUserControls);
        base.OnInit(e);
    }
}
```

Now I will be having ASPX Pages such as : ChildPage1.aspx and ChildPage2.aspx which will be inheriting from the baseform and not from System.Web.UI.Page (obviously).

What I want to know is, how do I write a different implementation in each ChildPage for an event belonging to the UserControl. That is, for example, I want to execute ChildPage1ClickEventHandler for the Button Click event in ChildPage1.aspx and ChildPage2ClickEventHandler for the Button Click event in ChildPage2.aspx

How do I go about this ? Please help.

Comment: Why do you want to handle the click event on the page?  Is there some other issue that you can't figure out that you are trying to avoid by doing this?

Comment: Nopes. Its like this - we add a usercontrol to a baseform. A lot of pages will inherit from the baseform and hence they will be inheriting the usercontrol as well.

Now I have a button in the usercontrol.. and while I can of course do find control on each page and add an event handler for the button in each page, I was wondering if there was something simpler or more elegant or "proper way of doing it" than this.


Each inheriting page will want to have a different functionality for this button. Thats the design of the application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ha, another open question of mine.

This was sometime ago and though I don't remember the scenario exactly, I know what I was looking for that day.

As I figured out sometime later, what you have to do is to expose the event (click or whatever event for that user control) and then attach event handlers to it in the child pages.

The other way to do that is to use delegates I believe (delegate the user control click event handling from the user control to the child page where you want to handle it)